# Hive Table DDL using Unix shell script

Tags: unix, hive

I am a novice in Unix and need some help.
I have a excel file in the below format.

**Table,Column,Datatype,Inputformat**

```
TableA,col1,int,TEXTFILE

TableA,col2,string,TEXTFILE

TableA,col3,float,TEXTFILE

TableA,col4,int,TEXTFILE

TableB,col1,string,TEXTFILE

TableB,col2,int,TEXTFILE

TableB,col3,int,TEXTFILE
```

Likewise I have records for 100 tables.

I need to create a ddl statement for hive table creation for all those 100 tables using unix.

e.g:

```
create table TableA(col1 int ,col2 string,col3 float,col4 int) STORED AS TEXTFILE;

create table TableB(col1 string ,col2 int,col3 int) STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Can you please help me with the approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You may prepare an awk script

```
awk  -F ',' '{ 
                 a[$1] = a[$1] " " $2 " " $3 ","; #read the column/dtype into array
                 b[$1] = $4 ;                     #read the file format
         }END{
              for (i in a ) #loop through the concatenated string
              { gsub(/,$/, ")" ,a[i] );           #replace last comma with ")"
                      print "CREATE TABLE " i " (" a[i] " STORED AS " b[i] ;
                  } 
                }' filename
```

Comment: NayakWhat if I want to give the Inputformat dynamically?                                                      e.g:                                                                                                                               Table,Column,Datatype,Inputformat

TableA,col1,int,TEXTFILE

TableA,col2,string,TEXTFILE

TableA,col3,float,TEXTFILE

TableA,col4,int,TEXTFILE

TableB,col1,string,SEQUENCEFILE

TableB,col2,int,SEQUENCEFILE

TableB,col3,int,SEQUENCEFILE

Comment: @SumitD : I've edited the script to handle that now.